# Kubernetes Helm, combine two variables with a string in the middle

Tags: kubernetes, go-templates, kubernetes-helm

I’m trying to change the value of a variable if another variable it set by combining the two with a dash in the middle, I’m not sure of the syntax to do this, I’m thinking of somethings like:

```
{{- $serviceNamespace := .Values.serviceNamespace -}}
{{- $serviceTag := .Values.serviceTag -}}
{{- if $serviceTag}}
{{- $serviceNamespace := .Values.serviceNamespace  "-" .Values.serviceTag -}}
{{- end}}
```

Is this correct? if `serviceNamespace` was `hello` and `serviceTag` was `1.0.0` would I end up with `serviceNamespace` being `hello-1.0.0`?

Comment: What is the need for reassigning $serviceNamespace variable again. Why can't use (( $serviceNamespace }} - {{ $serviceTag }}?

Answer (score 114):

For concatenation just use printf:

```
{{-  $serviceNamespace := printf "%s-%s" .Values.serviceNamespace .Values.serviceTag -}}
```

Comment: This gives me an error "mapping values are not allowed in this context"  on helm install, but still works... ???

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm going to post an issue to their github repo which shows how I used this to avoid a string casting issue to int inside a range loop!

Comment: or if you want to concatenate  string `name: {{ .Release.Name }}-mystring-chart`

Answer (score 78):

You can simply do it like this , with string ":" in middle

```
"{{ $values.image.repository }}:{{ $values.image.tag }}"
```

Comment: How would you apply a function with a pipe to this then?

Comment: @Any1 have you found out how to pass this into a pipe?

Answer (score 38):

**Update**

It is now possible in the **1.11** version of golang, see [commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/28c1ad9d35f27b3b57afff4ee78faac746a8ed0a):

```
{{- $serviceNamespace := .Values.serviceNamespace -}}
{{- $serviceTag := .Values.serviceTag -}}
{{- if $serviceTag}}
{{- $serviceNamespace = print .Values.serviceNamespace  "-" .Values.serviceTag -}}
{{- end}}
```

Notice the new `=` operator in `$serviceNamespace = print .Values.serviceNamespace "-" .Values.serviceTag`

**Older golang versions**

You cannot currently (in golang 1.9, but available in 1.11, see update above) reassign template variables because `if` introduces a new scope. Until this is fixed ([see issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10608) and [proposed fix](https://golang.org/cl/84480)), you can work around this by writing a function:

```
{{ define "makeServiceNamespace" }}
    {{- if .Values.serviceTag }}
    {{- printf "%s-%s" .Values.serviceNamespace .Values.serviceTag -}}
    {{- else }}
    {{- print .Values.serviceNamespace }}
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Then use it like so:

```
serviceNamespace: {{ template makeServiceNamespace . }}
```